# How i can change invalid string pattern with default string in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe like below.

```
name   birthdate
-----------------
john   21011990
steve  14021986
bob    
alice  13020198
```

i want to  detect invalid value in birthdate column then change value.

the birthdate column use date format is "DDMMYYYY" . but in dataframe have a invalid format also as "13020198","". i want to change invalid data to 31125000 .

i want result like below

```
name   birthdate
-----------------
john   21011990
steve  14021986
bob    31125000
alice  31125000
```

thank you

Comment: Why is `13020198` invalid? It follows the DDMMYYYY format

Comment: Do you want to preserve the dates as datetime, or keep the format?

Comment: `df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['birthdate'], format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce').isna(), 'birthdate'] = '31125000'` ..?

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to check if the last four digits are in a range, like between 1900 and 2020?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create non-valid date mask and then update their values:

```
mask = df.birthdate.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')).isna()

df.loc[mask, 'birthdate'] = 31125000

    name    birthdate
0   john    21011990
1   steve   14021986
2   bob     31125000
3   alice   31125000
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution to keep the format you specify:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'name':['J','S','B','A'],'birthdate':[21011990,14021986,'',13020198]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthdate'],format='%d%m%Y',errors='coerce').astype(str)
df['birthdate'] = df['birthdate'].str.replace('-','',regex=True).replace('NaT',31125000,regex=True).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  name  birthdate
0    J   19900121
1    S   19860214
2    B   31125000
3    A   31125000
```

Of course it'd be easier if you kept the datatime format, then you could simply use:

```
df['birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthdate'],format='%d%m%Y',errors='coerce').fillna(31125000)
print(df)
```

And you'd get:

```
  name            birthdate
0    J  1990-01-21 00:00:00
1    S  1986-02-14 00:00:00
2    B             31125000
3    A             31125000
```

Answer (score 0):

Create mask by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` and test missing values created if no matchin format, last set new values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df['birthdate'], format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce').isna()
df['birthdate'] = df['birthdate'].mask(m, 31125000)
```

Or @Chris A solution from comments with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[m, 'birthdate'] = 31125000
```

---

```
print (df)
    name birthdate
0   john  21011990
1  steve  14021986
2    bob  31125000
3  alice  31125000
```